# Add talks given to Careers profile

Tags: feature-request, jobs

The SO Careers page has a section for books and blogposts, but nothing to help show off presentations given at meetups and conferences. For instance, [I keep a tiny page on a wiki](https://github.com/Incognito/blog/wiki/Public-speaking-and-articles) about this, and I'd rather keep all my content like this in one place. I'd love to see this feature!